# Mounting NAS for plex media server on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, permissions, fstab, nas, mountpoint

I know there are a lot of already asked questions in the web concerning plex server and ubuntu but none of the solutions worked for me.
I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS clean install. I installed plex media server to which I have access via web browser so I think this works fine. Since all my media files are on diffrent NAS, I need to mount these. For this I created a folder in my home directory /home/video/movies to which I assigned

```
sudo chown -R username:plex /home/video/movies
sudo chmod -R 770 /home/video/movies
```

to mount I added the following line to my /etc/fstab file:

```
//static_ip_to _nas/movies    /home/video/movies  cifs  uid=1000,username=yyy,password=xxx,vers=2.0
```

I tried diffrent setups with adding gid,rw and so on but the posted setup showed the best result considering write access. But when I try to add a mediafolder to plex via webbrowser plex is not doing anything. When I check the permissions of the mounted movies folder there is no plex user shown even it was shown before mounting the NAS. I also tried the uid from the plex user for the fstab file but this didn't work eather. 
The second problem is the second NAS which is also a QNAP NAS like the first one only a newer version. When I set the same command like above for the second NAS and run sudo mount -a  I get an error that this action is not supported. Why is this and how can I succesfully add my mediafolder to plex?

UPDATE:

before mount

```
ls -la /home/max/video/movies

total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 770 plex 4096 Mär 14 20:05 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 770 plex 4096 Mär 14 20:05 ..
```

after mount

```
ls -la /home/max/video/movies

total 180
drwxr-xr-x 2 max root      0 Mär 12 21:17 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 770 plex   4096 Mär 14 20:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 max root      0 Nov 10 14:01 movie1
drwxr-xr-x 2 max root      0 Feb 20 17:20 movie2
.
.
.
```

The error message I'm getting while mounting the second NAS is:

```
mount: mount //192.168.178.5/Max/Video/Mediathek/Movies on /home/max/mediathek/video/movies failed: Operation not supported
```

Is it possible that the error has something to do with port bundling of the NAS?

Comment: Can you add a bit more information: error massages of the `mount /home/video/movies` command, `ls -la /home/video/movies` befor and after the mount, etc...

Comment: I updated the requested information

Comment: I don't think, it has something to do with port bundling or the mods/users. Try setting the CIFS version.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the other problem, I mean that plex won't find any media in the mounted directory?

Comment: Let's fix the mount issue first... I assume they are related

Comment: thank you, adding a version worked but still no success in plex. I changed the plex user name to my username in /etc/default/plexmediaserver but this wont work eather.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but I had a similar issue with a NAS and the CIFS version. Try to specify the version of the CIFS in `/etc/fstab` (and also start with read-only for testing):

```
//nas_srv/folder /mnt/folder cifs uid=1000,username=yyy,password=xxx,vers=1.0,ro
```

Comment: I tried this but I only recive this message:                                    mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //192.168.178.5/Max/Video/Mediathek/Movies,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

Comment: did you check the syslog and dmesg?

Comment: okay, it seemed like I was using an unsupported samba version. I am now able to mount all my NAS shares. But still plex wont find any media in the mounted directories